# Laravel 502 Bad Gateway Nginx when it's high Traffic

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I'm using a Laravel App,below is my nginx configuration code:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    root /var/www/project/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

    charset utf-8;
    location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/domain.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

**Error Log**

```
2018/06/29 08:41:30 [error] 928#928: *14875 connect() to unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: IP, server: IP, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "IP"
```

Is something wrong with my config? I'm having a heavy servers with 32GB Ram, SSD and processor: 2x E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz. I'm using Ubuntu with NGINX.

Kindly let me know, I've changed many servers but not able to get rid off this issue.

Comment: I would imagine that this is more likely to be an issue with the PHP fpm config than nginx. What are you PHP memory limits like?

Comment: @Joe please help me with that if you can. That would be so much appreciated

Comment: Are there any messages in your error log?

Comment: @Jerodev just updated my question with the Error Log

Answer (score 0):

Check your php-fpm logs to see if nginx is dying. The error you are getting is Nginx saying that the server it is proxying requests to is not answering. This could be a network issue if they are on two different machines, it could be from there not being enough workers to satisfy all of the incoming requests, it could be from the OOM killer on a VPS killing the process. Just because a server has a ton of RAM doesn't mean it impervious to memory exhaustion. I have had a customer with a Magento site who's end of day reports threw memory errors on a server with similar specs due to the poorly coded plugin.

I just saw that you posted a line from your log. Check your pool.conf for the following:

process.max, pm.max_children, pm.min/max_spare_servers

These are just a few of the things you may need to tweak in a heavy traffic environment.